# How to link QT and OpenCV in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, linker

I'm trying to link QT with the OpenCV library, but I can't.
OpenCV works, Qt works, but I can't work with both together.

I add a build step in the Qt creator, and this kind of work, I mean, I write cv:: and automatically a list has been show with all methods of OpenCV, but when I compile, I have around 20 errors, with OpenCV methods.

But, if i compile the same code in terminal, without Qt, all is fine.

Anyone knows how to link **Correctly** OpenCV and Qt?
Please help :(

Qt version: 5.2.1
Qt Creator version: 3.0.1
OpenCV version: 2.4.8

PD: remember, I'm using Linux, there are thousands of tutorials about this but in windows :/

PD2: Sorry for my English.

Edit: This is an example of my error, this happen with all OpenCV methods, like imread and waitKey

error: undefined reference to `cv::getRotationMatrix2D(cv::Point_, double, double)'

Comment: Why don't you paste your errors here, so that we can see what the problem is?

Comment: How are you linking the OpenCV library? Do you have section in your .pro file to link in the libraries: LIBS += -lopencv_core248 -lopencv_highgui248

Comment: Actually no, I just add a path in projects/build steps. Its usr/local/include. Im not editing files. Which file need to edit?

Comment: You will have a project file with the extension .pro, which is accessible in the Edit view. You will need to add a LIBS line to that to tell it which libraries you want to include.

Answer (score 1):

In your QtCreators Edit view you need to add a link to the library files, on my setup I have this within my .pro file:

```
CONFIG += use_webcam_opencv
```

...

```
use_webcam_opencv {
    message("Using OpenCV Webcam")
    LIBS += -lopencv_core247 -lopencv_highgui247
    HEADERS +=  widgets/camerawidget.h \
                widgets/camerawindow.h
    SOURCES +=  widgets/camerawidget.cpp \
                widgets/camerawindow.cpp
}
```

The `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` are of course my own, since I only compile them if I enable OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks, but this its kind of strange for me, i know how to use opencv, but i have no idea about Qt, BTW, thanks :-D

Answer (score 1):

Do you have pkg-config configured/installed with opencv?
You can check by simply typing 'pkg-config `pkg-config opencv --libs`. If you get any output, you're good.

Then, in QT, just edit *.pro* project setting file and add the following line(I had to put the image as I didn't know how to put those quotes in an answer) :-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CMjX.jpg

Sample .pro file : http://pastebin.com/KDYqW5Wj

Should Work

Comment: Ok thanks, finally works, I add the "LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --libs`" line and now compile :). But... it craches during the compilation, the error message its about *.so files. BTW, thanks :)

Comment: Did you compile OpenCV(not your project) or did you download it from a repo?

Comment: I download the opencv zip from the oficial web, the I just follow the installation instructions, OpenCV it's not the problem, Qt either, i just dont know how to link both correctly :)